# How to display text depending on the number in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I work on the app with some calculate function. I have a `UITextField` where user enter a number and `UILabel` where is result. How can I display some text in second `UILabel` depending on the number in the first UILabel?

Example:

```
If number in *firstLabel less than 20, then display in *secondLabel: small

If number in *firstLabel from 20 to 30, then display in *secondLabel: normal

If number in *firstLabel greater than 40, then display in *secondLabel: big
```

I hope you understood what i mean. Thank you! Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to get the int value from your **firstLabel**, Which is stored as text, you could get it by using `NSString` `intValue` function.

Use the below

```
int intValueFromFirstLabel = [firstLabel.text intValue];

if(intValueFromFirstLabel < 20)
{
  secondLabel.text = @"small";
}
else if(intValueFromFirstLabel >= 20 && intValueFromFirstLabel <= 30)
{
  secondLabel.text = @"normal";
}
else if(intValueFromFirstLabel > 40)
{
  secondLabel.text = @"big";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([firstLabel.text intValue] <20)
{
    secondLabel .text=@"small";
}
else if(([firstLabel.text intValue] >=20) && ([firstLabel.text intValue] <=30) )
{
    secondLabel .text=@"normal";
}
else if([firstLabel.text intValue] >30)
{
    secondLabel .text=@"big";
}
```

Comment: Why calling `intValue` in 4 places when you can do that once? Helps readability, and also easier to change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code

```
 lblFirst.text = txtField.text;
 int intValue = [lblFirst.text intValue];
 if (intValue < 20) {
    lblSecond.text = @"Small";
 } else if (intValue >= 20 && intValue <= 30) {
    lblSecond.text = @"Normal";
 } else if (intValue > 40) {
    lblSecond.text = @"Big";
 }
```